# What does "pluck" mean in football/soccer term

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "pluck" mean in football/soccer context?

Steffen **plucks** a free-kick from the left, awarded for Bernardo's foul on Pulisic, out of the heavens as it drops. One more minute at most.

Answer (score 1):

**pluck:** verb:

to remove someone suddenly from a situation that is ordinary:
He was **plucked** from obscurity to star in the film.

to remove someone quickly from a dangerous or difficult situation:
The last passengers were **plucked** from the ship just seconds before it sank

So in this case the commentator is using poetic liecense and using the word pluck to create an image of Steffen magically obtaining almost out of thin air a free-kick in this moment of need.

[**CED- pluck**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pluck)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is actually a misunderstanding and the commentator said “plunk” instead of pluck. “Plunk” is used quite often in sports to signify an easier or rather unremarkable goal.